# Chi Square Ratio Test on proportions with sum over 1

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, proportion, count-data

I want to use Chi Square test for two proportions to find out the statistical significance of the difference. However, the two proportions do not sum up to 1.

For example, suppose I have a publication dataset and want to compare the productivity between male and female. Since there may be co-authorship relationship, female and male may have co-authored some papers. Therefore, I might end up with proportions such as:Female (35% of the total papers); Male 70% of the total paper.

Is it still possible to test (35%, 70%) (or equivalently the count data) against a given expected ratio? If so, what is the reasonable way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: This won't be binomial and you won't have independence

Comment: @Glen_b This means I cannot use Chi Square Ratio Test to compare the ratios, right?

Comment: I don't think so - not as it stands, if you had the individual-level data of who wrote with whom on what papers and a clear null and alternative you might be able to do something.